# Change the step of a histogram in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm using plotly.js to try to represent a statistical dataset.
i.e draw a histgram for sizes.
My trace is the following

```
const trace = {
 type: 'histogram',
 x: [1.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.65, 1.9, 1.62, 1.76, 1.74, 1.82, 1.7]
}
```

Then I use it with `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace]);`

But the histogram I get has steps of 0.1, meaning that I get only 3 columns for 1.6-1.69, 1.7-1.79 and 1.8-1.89.
The question is simple, how to change it to have a step of, for example, 0.05 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xbins property for example

```
const trace = {
 type: 'histogram',
 xbins: {size: 0.05, start: 0, end: 2},
 x: [1.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.65, 1.9, 1.62, 1.76, 1.74, 1.82, 1.7]
}
```